# Handling Boolean resultset in java

Tags: java, boolean, resultset

I have one query that returns string value, my query is

select case when (select count (distinct style_packing_spec_id) from packing_spec_uses_pack p,style_pack sp where sp.style_pack_id=p.style_pack_id and sp.style_id=1701) != (select count (distinct style_packing_spec_id) from style_packing_spec where style_id=1701) then 'DonotProceed' else 'Proceed' end ";
It gives result as below

```
 ?case?
----------
 DonotProceed
```

how to execute this is in java, how to handle this result set,I tried like this

```
String sql="query";
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

It returns nullpointerexception
    String str=rs.getString(1);

Comment: And did you get any error messages that you are not telling us about? Such as "invalid column index 0" or "cursor before the first row"?

Comment: It shows type mismatch error cannot convert from boolean to Boolean,

Comment: Please do not change your question after asking it (from returning a boolean to returning a String)

Comment: you give ans for my first question,ignore my second one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never had boolean returned from a query (Oracle doesn't do that...), but I assume that it works. You just need to go to the first row of the result set, and the column index starts with 1 (not 0).

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
try{
  rs.next();                // move to the first row
  return rs.getBoolean(1);  // first column is 1
}
finally{
  rs.close();
}
```

**Update:**

> It shows type mismatch error cannot convert from boolean to Boolean

Are you using Java 1.4 ? For Java5 and above, this should be taken care of by auto-boxing. But you can also fix it by using a primitive boolean variable to match what JDBC returns:

```
boolean str = rs.getBoolean(1); // I question the variable name, though
```

Comment: Pls kindly note my edited query it shows null pointer exception

Comment: java version "1.4.2_18" my java version

Comment: Thilo,with the help of your above code i did it correctly. thanks a lot